# Integration with modulus

Tags: integration

I have to integrate

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^3|At|\sin\pi nt dt
\end{equation}

and try to get rid of the modulus. How do I do that, or how do I consider it in the integration procedure?

I tried "ignoring" it, and just integrate by integration by parts:

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^3|At|\sin\pi nt dt=\frac{-|At|\cos \pi n t}{\pi n}+\frac{|A|}{\pi n}\int_{-1}^3|At|\cos\pi nt dt
\end{equation}

getting

\begin{equation}
\frac{-|At|\cos \pi n t}{\pi n}+\frac{|A|}{\pi n}\int_{-1}^3|At|\cos\pi nt dt=\bigg[\frac{-|At|\cos \pi n t}{\pi n}+\frac{|A|\sin\pi nt}{\pi^2 n^2}\bigg]_{-1}^3 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\bigg[\frac{-|At|\cos \pi n t}{\pi n}+\frac{|A|\sin\pi nt}{\pi^2 n^2}\bigg]_{-1}^3 = \frac{-2|A|}{\pi n}(-1)^n
\end{equation}

But I suspect this is incorrect.

What would be the best way to solve this type of integrals?
Thanks!

UPDATE;
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^3|At|\sin\pi nt dt=-\int_{-1}^0 At\sin\pi nt dt+\int_{0}^3 At\sin\pi nt dt
\end{equation}

Comment: See the interval over which you are integrating

Comment: A little bit more specific....?

Comment: Basically your lower and upper limit constitute the lower and upper boundary of the interval. So the $|At|$ will have a negative sign from -1 to 0 and a positive sign from 0 to 3. You'll have to split the integral into these 2 pieces

Comment: I see, but how can |At| get a negative sign between -1 and 0, when it is modulus, which implies always positive? Does this mean that one ALWAYS ignores the modulus for negative intervals?

Comment: I'll type up an answer, give me a few mins.

Comment: Ok, thanks.......

Comment: in general, it is good to split up an absolute function like this into two (or more sometimes) cases like you stated in your update. Whilst it is possible to define the indefinite integral then evaluate, splitting it up is much easier

Answer (score 2):

In your integral, -1 and 3 represent the interval over which you consider integrating the function; $(-1,3)$. And remember that the modulus of a function always returns its positive value, so,
$$|f(x)|=f(x) \text{ if } f(x)>=0$$
and
$$|f(x)|=-f(x) \text{ if } f(x)<0$$

So in your $|At|$, t, being variable, will take up a negative value within $(-1,0)$ and a positive value within $(0,3)$. The method to handle this is to split the integral into these separate domains with corresponding upper and lower limits. Evaluate them separately thereafter and sum their contributions.

Though, if n is an integer, the integral is automatically zero cause $\sin(n\pi t)$ is zero.

Comment: Thanks, Does the update look good in the original post?